# Git push heroku main > pre-receive hook declined

Tags: node.js, heroku

When I give the command `git push heroku main` it fails to build and shows the following error:

```
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: The error is probably related to the Security incident, Github integration has been disabled for sure, it may be that git push deployment is disabled as well. To find out more you can check their status page. https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413

Comment: @NoNameProvided, there is no evidence of that. Plus, OP appears to be using `git push` to deploy, not GitHub integration.

Comment: OP, these lines are the _least_ useful from your logs. All the important bits are above this. Please [edit] your question and show us the complete error output.